# Adding an abstract property to UML class diagrams using Visual Studio 2012 RTM

Tags: oop, visual-studio-2012, uml, class-diagram

How does one add an abstract property in UML class diagram using Visual Studio 2012 RTM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must track the following steps :

1. Define a profile to extend UML :

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465145.aspx
2. Add stereotypes to model elements :

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465145.aspx
3. Customize your model with profiles and stereotypes :

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's not possible to define an abstract property in UML class diagram of VS 2012 RTM. Instead of it, you must add an interface that's contains the property and all favorite classes implement it.